# How to create an active_link_to current_page helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I give an `active font-weight-bold` class to active links like this:

```
      <li class="<%= 'active font-weight-bold' if current_page?(root_path) %> nav-item">
        <%= link_to "Homepage" root_path, class: 'nav-link' %>
      </li>
```

How can I write a helper so that would reduce the code to something like

```
      <%= active_link_to "Homepage", root_path %>
```

or with a block

```
      <%= active_link_to root_path do %>
        Homepage
      <% end %>
```

My thoughts are somewhere around this :

```
#application_helper.rb

def active_link_to(name, path, class)
  if current_page?(path)
    content_tag(:span, name, class: "active font-weight-bold nav-link")
  else
    content_tag(:span, name, class: "nav-link")
  end
end
```

(this does not work)

Comment: Check out this gist ... https://gist.github.com/pelted/5dac756f690a61f698145dc9495a9633

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include `<a>` tag in `li` i.e. `link_to` in `li`.

```
def active_link_to(name, path, class = 'nav-link')
  content_tag(:li, class: "#{'active font-weight-bold' if current_page?(path)} #{class}") do
     link_to name, path, class: class
   end
end
```

& then

```
<%= active_link_to "Homepage" root_path %>
```

Comment: thanks Salil, this works! Can you please also help to figure out how this helper would look for `<%= active_link_to root_path do %> "Homepage  <% end %>`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked:

#### link_to "homepage", root_path

```
  def active_link_to(name, path)
    content_tag(:li, class: "#{'active font-weight-bold' if current_page?(path)} nav-item") do
      link_to name, path, class: "nav-link"
    end
  end
```

works like

```
<%= active_link_to "homepage" root_path %>
```

#### link_to root_path do "homepage" (with a block)

```
  def active_link_to(path)
    content_tag(:li, class: "#{'active font-weight-bold' if current_page?(path)} nav-item") do
      link_to path, class: "nav-link" do
        yield
      end
    end
  end
```

works like

```
<%= link_to root_path do %>
  homepage
<% end %>
```